# SSO and Rails Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, single-sign-on

I'm currently integrating my company's SSO solution with my Rails 3.1.3 application.

I'm using Apache with the company's SiteMinder module enabled to do this.  SiteMinder re-routes the request based on their SSO authentication status.  Once authenticated, the SiteMinder module then re-routes EVERY request to their central URL to see if their authenticity token has expired.  It re-builds the authenticity token, and then re-directs back to my Rails app.

While all of this is going on, my users' Rails sessions are being reset at a seemingly random interval.  I know this because the session ID cookie's value changes.

This only happens when SiteMinder is enabled.  When I turn it off, the Rails sessions persist as expected.

What is the conflict here?  Is Rails somehow aware of the redirect that takes place by the SiteMinder module?  My app is deployed using Passenger; if I change the PassengerSpawnMethod to conservative, would that help?